# XML Schema Regular Expression

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I'm having trouble with two regular expressions that I need to use to validate `url`s in an `xsd` file.

I understand that there is a slight difference in how `Schema` uses regex compared to other systems.

Does anyone have any valid regex to separately validate a `url` and an `email` in `XSD` schema?

Answer (score 0):

For e-mail :

```
<xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"/>
```

Not that xsd schema always implies anchors so this should have to match your entire string.

Edit : Above regex is pretty basic. I suggest you read this :

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

For more info. Regarding the url, depending on how complex you want your validation to be there are about a million regexes you could use. And schema regex is rather limited to say the least.

Comment: There are plenty of valid email addresses not matched here.